# How to typeset projective module diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a projective module type diagram like the diagram given in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.What you try so far? Or you have preferences whit which program (package) you like to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First version with Xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  & P \ar@{.>}[dl]_{h} \ar[d]^{f} \\
A \ar@{->>}[r]^g & B \ar[r] & 0
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Improved version with Xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  & P \ar@{.>}[dl]_{h} \ar[d]^{f} \\
A \ar@{->>}[r]^g & B \ar[r] & 0
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version with `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  & P \arrow[dl,dotted,swap,"h"] \arrow[d,"f"] \\
A \arrow[r,two heads,"g"] & B \arrow[r] & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Comments

The first version looks exactly like your picture, which was almost surely produced in the same way. The arrow tips are, however, awful and don't mix with the other arrows in the document. This is cured in the second version by adding `cmtip`.

What's are the advantages in switching to `tikz-cd`? There are so many that a list would be impossible.

The syntax is easier: in the options to `\arrow` you specify the target, then possibly the arrow type and the label; the standard position is on the left (going from source to target) and the option swap allows for changing the side. The label is input by enclosing it between quotes.

Another important aspect is that the arrow tips generally agree with the main document math font, which is not possible with Xy-pic.

Comment: How do I maximize the size(scaling) of the diagram in your first answer?

Comment: @Sucre Why would you want to scale it?

Comment: Cause it shows relatively small on the pdf

Comment: @Sucre You can increase the size by something like `\xymatrix@C+1pc@R+1pc{...}`; I wouldn't scale the letters.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `tikz-cd` and a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.2, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=2pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=0.6cm, colsep = 1.1cm, shortput=tab, linejoin=1}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
%%%nodes
 & P\\%
 A & B & 0%%%
  %%% arrows
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2}>[tpos =0.4]{f}
 \ncline[linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt]{1,2}{2,1}^[ tpos=0.48]{h}
 \ncline[arrows=->>]{2,1}{2,2}^{g} \ncline{2,2}{2,3}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
 &P \dar{f}\dlar[ swap, dashed]{h} \\%
 A \rar[two heads]{g} & B \rar & 0\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]